# SQL select procedure : how to select a range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, if-statement

I have this procedure:

```
 USE myDataBase

 DECLARE 
  @id INT = NULL
 ,@name VARCHAR(250)= NULL
 ,@id2 INT = NULL
 ,@flag INT =NULL

 SELECT *
    FROM    dbo.table1  INNER JOIN
            dbo.table2 ON id = id2 

   WHERE (@id IS NULL OR @id = id)
   AND (@name IS NULL OR @name = name)
   AND (@id2 IS NULL OR @id2 = id2)
```

Depending on what @flag contains, I need @id2 in where clause to be in a centain range.

Meaning

```
if @flag = 2 --@flag can contain any value from 1 to 12
```

I need this line:

```
AND (@id2 IS NULL OR @id2 = id2)
```

To be:

```
AND (@id2 IS NULL OR @id2 IN (61,62,63))
```

Also:

```
if @flag = 4 --@flag can contain any value from 1 to 12
```

I need this line:

```
AND (@id2 IS NULL OR @id2 = id2)
```

To be:

```
AND (@id2 IS NULL OR @id2 IN (74,75,76))
```

And so on..

How can I do that?

I know is a stupid question, but I cannot make it work :(

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you might be trying to use one query where several could be more appropriate. It's certainly up to you, but I'd be tempted to handle the `@flag` parameter outside your T-Sql, for instance in C# or whatever you're using, and call a pre-written query based on its value. This way just seems more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a temporary table variable, and query using the contents of that variable.

```
DECLARE @IdList TABLE
(
    Id INT,
)

-- Populate temporary table variable with required Id's depending on @flag value
IF @flag = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @IdList VALUES (@id2)
END

IF @flag = 2
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @IdList VALUES (61), (62), (63)
END

IF @flag = 4
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @IdList VALUES (74), (75), (76)
END

-- Code for other flag values within 1-12


-- Perform query to get results
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Temp) = 0
BEGIN
    -- No values provided for matching
     SELECT *
       FROM dbo.table1
            INNER JOIN dbo.table2 ON id = id2
      WHERE (@id IS NULL OR @id = id)
        AND (@name IS NULL OR @name = name)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     -- One or more values provided for matching
     SELECT *
       FROM dbo.table1
            INNER JOIN dbo.table2 ON id = id2
                   AND id2 IN (SELECT Id FROM @IdList)
      WHERE (@id IS NULL OR @id = id)
        AND (@name IS NULL OR @name = name)
END
```

It's not clear how you're handling `@id2 = NULL` so the final `IF` clause is to separate the two.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
AND ((@flag = 2 AND @id2 IS NULL OR @id2 IN (61,62,63)) OR
    (@id2 IS NULL OR @id2 = id2) )
```

EDIT:

```
AND (((@flag >= 1 AND @flag <=12) AND @id2 IS NULL OR @id2 IN (61,62,63)) OR
    (@id2 IS NULL OR @id2 = id2) )
```

Comment: This was what I had gone to originally, but if `@flag` is in the proper range but `@id` isn't in (61,62,63), it'll move on to check if `@id2 = id2`. I got the impression that that wasn't the desired behavior.

Comment: It might not be the desired behaviour, but it is the answer to his question